# IS it possible to run GRASS commands in the QGIS graphical modeler?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-plugins, qgis-modeler

I have a geoalgorithm set up in the graphical modeler and everything runs except for the GRASS commands. It is really frustrating because when I execute these commands on their own they work just fine but as soon as I run them as part of a larger process they simply do not produce the desired results. I am using the mapcalc command to extract raster values below 10, for example.

Comment: I didn't work with GRASS in the QGIS modeler but are you importing the rasters to your GRASS Mapset inside the modeler as you have to do using GRASS commands outside it? Are there commands you're using that only GRASS offers? Extract Values below 10 could be done by the SAGA raster calculator as well for example

Comment: Are you getting an error message in the log? What are the exact symptoms? Would be helpful to see the code, too.